# Configure Traffic for VPN

Tags: networking, vpn

I am having issues accessing remtote resources using the Cato VPN client. The subnet that I am connecting to via VPN looks like

```
192.168.1.0/24
192.168.2.0/24
...
```

And my home network wifi interface / network looks like

```
wlp58s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.98  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::e306:14d0:1888:c6b7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2604:2000:12c1:c42a:0:a0c3:8dc2:729c  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2604:2000:12c1:c42a:14a4:c462:d46a:8396  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2604:2000:12c1:c42a:8c06:b847:efda:159a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 9c:b6:d0:d5:24:05  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1382636  bytes 1411037937 (1.4 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 354583  bytes 73040708 (73.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

when I attempt to acess `192.168.1.11` I get a server address IP could not be found error. I believe the issue is that `192.168.1.11` is being looked for locally on my home network, instead of over the VPN. One solution would be to change my home network to something else like `192.168.7.0/24` but I'm wondering if there are any other options?

The output for `ip route` with the client active is

```
default dev tun0 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp58s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
45.62.183.62 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp58s0 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp58s0 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp58s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.98 metric 600 
192.168.1.4 dev tun0
```

Without the vpn `ip route` shows

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp58s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp58s0 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp58s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.98 metric 600
```

Comment: Would you mind posting `ip route`?  This will tell us where your system looks for IP addresses.

Comment: Sure, just updated the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the problem in the `ip route`.  Number 6 says the route to all `192.168.1.0/24` ip addresses is on device `wlp58s0`.  This takes priority over rule 1 which says the default gateway is `tun0` (the VPN).  You seem to have diagnosed the problem correctly.

Normally VPNs wouldn't use a subnet that's so common because it will be prone to issues like this.  If you're ever on a network where you don't control the IPs such as a public wifi you won't be able to use the VPN.

The best solution would probably change the VPN subnet to something more unique like `10.X.Y.0/24` and set your firewall rules so that this subnet has access to the remote `192.168.1.0/24` subnet.

If that's not an option you could change your home subnet, but this isn't a portable solution.

Finally, you could delete the rule:

```
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp58s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.98 metric 600
```

This would solve your problem, but cost you access to your local subnet.  Also messing with your routing tables manually is risky if you don't understand networks very well.

Comment: Thanks @user2752635. I previously spoke with some Cato support and they claimed the issue was to do with my home subnet, `192.168.1.0/24` being the same as the subnet that I am trying to connect to over VPN? But it sounds like this is not the issue, and as long as I set up the VPN tunnel such that it properly routes than I shouldn't have an issue? I imagine this setting is done somewhere in the VPN configuration?

Comment: So the issue comes down to with the way your networks are set-up, there isn't really a good way to route.  If both your home and VPN subnets are the same, then the routing tables have no way to know which `192.168.1.0/24` you want to connect to.  Either your home or your remote network nned to have a different subnet in order to correctly route to both.  The solution they proposed would work, but since `192.168.1.0/24` is a very common subnet, I wouldn't consider that reliable.  Instead, I would change the remote subnet to something less common.